# How replace <br> with linebreak in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can I replace my binding data's < br > with line break?
like: passing data:
Hello< br >welcome to this group< br >type your text

and viewing data will be :
Hello
welcome to this group
type your text

to replace < br > with line break, I have used [innerHTML] like, <p  [innerHTML]="a.Details">

; but here problem is, all letter are come as Capital formate.
Is there any alter form?

Comment: Check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different div.

eg.

```
<div> Hello </div>
<div> welcome to this group </div>
<div> type your text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to update your code :

```
<p [innerHTML]="replaceBreaksWithLineBreaks(a.Details.toLowerCase())"></p>
```

**and your JS function**

```
 replaceBreaksWithLineBreaks(text: string): string {
  return text.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the text from `<br>` and will have an array of each line.
on the HTML side you can loop through the lines and use `<p *ngFor=let line of text>{{line}}</P>` to display them.

.ts file

```
  text: string = 'Hello< br >welcome to this group< br >type your text';

  lines: string[] = this.text.split('< br >');
```

.html file

```
<p *ngFor="let line of lines">{{line}}</p>
```